# I think I was low balled when I accepted a job. Am I just screwed?

Tags: negotiation, raise

How can I find out and/or get a raise? Raises apparently don't happen too often here. I also did zero negotiating because that just scares me. I am a sissy, I know. On the other hand, how can I find out if I was under paid because there is the possibility that I wasn't.

Comment: Is there a contract?  In what country is this taking place?

Comment: You're pretty much screwed, yes. You accepted a wage. But don't feel too bad. At one point you were satisfied with that number. Don't let what others make affect your personal satisfaction. As for getting more money, you're likely going to have to find a new job to do that.  Bide your time and do just that or after a certain period, ask for a raise.

Comment: You could quit and try to get another job at a higher salary.

Comment: You accepted the offer.  Suck it up.

Comment: I would definitely chalk this up as a learning experience for your next job. Try to learn how to be assertive, eventually you will see that only you will stick up for yourself.

Answer (score 6):

You're underpaid if you're working for less than what someone is willing to pay you.

The most effective way to determine what the job market thinks you're worth is to apply for other jobs, interview, and see what you're offered.

The "secret" to good negotiating is to have confidence in yourself and be willing to walk away from the negotiation.  If you are interviewing for your next job while you still have your present job, you always have the ability to decline the offer if you think it is too low.

Answer (score 4):

You'll find yourself in a much healthier place, over the long term, if you don't fall prey to the ["comparison game"](http://www.becomingminimalist.com/compare-less/).  I don't care if you spend 100 years on a job -- there's ALWAYS, and I mean ALWAYS going to be someone around where you may feel they're not worth what the company's paying.  This will be co-workers, bosses, subordinates.

At this place you're at - and you seem upset - you give away your power to any situation where you seem to be earning less money than someone else who isn't necessarily "better" than you at the job.  You'll drive yourself crazy.  *We aren't put here to be the same as everybody else*.

I've left a good link above that might interest you.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Q:  On the other hand, how can I find out if I was under paid because there is the possibility that I wasn't.
A:  There are many sites that show salary by level, location, job, title, etc.  http://www.glassdoor.com is one.

Answer (score 0):

Life lesson. If you accept a low offer, then keep in mind that you'll get a normal 2-3% raise while other, new folks coming in potentially having a better gap than you do. Basically by the time you get a 10-15% raise, assuming you do something exceptional by year 4 or 5, then someone new will only make within a smaller gap of that. Basically by low balling yourself, you lock your ability to appear better because you make nearly the same as someone who is just now coming in.

Comment: Assuming anyone gets a 2-3% raise seems optimistic these days.  While that might be "average" many organizations are getting negative raises or less than 2%.  Some might get a 2-3% raise yet see healthcare premiums increase, deductibles increase, benefits cut, parking increase, etc.